# Empty classes.jar file in the aar dependency

Tags: android, gradle, jar, dependencies, aar

I have created a library project and published the same in private maven repo in nexus. I was able to publish the aar successfully and I had included the same in an external project. While adding the dependency in gradle, the app is built successfully. But I am seeing an empty classes.jar file in the External dependencies tree in the project. Hence the java classes that I wrote in the library cannot be resolved. But the res directory is completely visible and is included. What I am doing wrong here?
[image]

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: yes. And I added rule -keep class com.mobscale.**{*;} also which is my package name

Comment: @HarikrishnanCV Having the same issue. Found any solutions?